# Removing white space in HTML button

Tags: html, css, button, position, css-position

So I'm coding an exit button for a client I'm making based in electron, and after figuring out how to re-size it according to screen size, the button shows a white space beside it. When I try and move it to the correct location it creates a huge white box under it too. Does anyone know why this is happening and could help me fix it?

```
<body>
    <webview src="https://bapbap.gg"></webview>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo+Black">
    <style>
      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
      }
      
      webview {
        flex: 1;
      }
      
      .ExitButton {
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: 'Archivo Black';
        color: #6B7075;
        border-color: transparent;
        background-color: transparent;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
        transform: translate(700px, 300px);
      }
      
      .ExitButton:hover {
        background-color: rgb(150, 5, 5);
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
      }
      
      .nav {
        display: flex;
      }

    </style>
    <div class="nav">
      <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('Are you sure you want to exit BapClient?')">EXIT</button>
    </div>
    </button>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

in class `ExitButton`, the line `transform: translate(700px, 300px);` is responsible to move the button from [0,0] to the point that you mentioned: [700,300].

By removing that line, you can get your button just on left&top of the page. Then you can use grids, layouts, etc. to change the location to wherever you want.